# Почему while нагружает страницу js

Tags: javascript, циклы, while

В цикле проходит некоторая проверка, но до нужной пора break игнорируется, в чем причина?

```
var one_words = ['كِتَابُ', 'مِحْبَرَةُ', 'لَوْحُ', 'قَلَمُ', 'كُرَّاسُ', 'نَشَّافَة', 'مِسْطَرَة'];
random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * one_words.length);
let i;

while (one_words[random_num] == '') {
        if (i > 30) {
            break;
        } else {
            random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * one_words.length);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Это отрывок кода, и в другом месте элементам массива приравнивается пустая строка

**Иное решение:**

```
while (one_words[random_num] == '' && i < 100)
```

Но в любом случае интересно, почему предыдущий код не получался?

Answer (score 4):

Ваш код не работает впринципе. Посмотрите на условие, которое вы поставили для работы цикла while `one_words[random_num] == ""`, оно не может сработать так как в массиве `one_words` не содержится пустых строк.

Если Вы хотите что бы цикл работал, его условие должно возвращать `true`.

```js
// скопировал сюда Ваш код, добавив вывод в консоль
// и заменил значения в массиве на латинские символы
// сейчас Вам должно быть видно
// что условие while не срабатывает
// а значение i остается неизменным 

const one_words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]  

let random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * one_words.length)

let i = 0

while (one_words[random_num] === "") {

        console.log("in while")

        if (i > 30) {
            break
        } else {
            random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * one_words.length)
            i++
        }
}

console.log(i)
```

Так же, для того что бы избежать возможных ошибок, всегда старитесь использовать проверку на [строгое соответствие](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison#strogoe-sravnenie) вместо [приведения к типу](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison#sravnenie-raznyh-tipov).

Answer (score 1):

```
let i;
```

Тут в i будет `undefined`, а потом

```
i++
```

будет `NaN` и поэтому break не пройдет.

нужно инициализировать i так

```
let i = 0;
```